# Hibernate auto table generation from domain class is not working in Grails with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

All the domain classes are being mapped as tables in MySQL instead of one domain class named **USER** (Name of the table is changed to `db_user` in mapping to avoid keyword violations) as shown below[image]:

And application keeps showing error on startup :

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'umm.db_user' doesn't exist**

**Versions of stack:**

| Grails Version: 3.2.3

| Groovy Version: 2.4.7

| JVM Version: 1.8.0_242

| Gradle: 3.0

| MySQL: 8.0.26-cluster

| Hibernate: 5.1.1.Final

**application.groovy**

[image: application.groovy]

**application.yml**

[image]

Logs:

```
2021-09-02 02:43:09.722 ERROR 26370 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'umm.db_user' doesn't exist
2021-09-02 02:43:09.783 ERROR 26370 --- [           main] grails.app.init.umm1.BootStrap           : Exception occured in bootstrap: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet 
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1905)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResultViaListCall(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:785)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResult(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:775)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'umm.db_user' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor187.invoke(Unknown Source) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementDecoratorInterceptor$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementDecoratorInterceptor.java:261)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.executeQuery(Unknown Source) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Grails application running at http://localhost:9091/umm in environment: development
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your config it is difficult to say for sure but it looks like `dbCreate` may be set to something that prevents DDL from being generated and sent to the db at startup.  Is there another `dataSource` config anywhere in your app that is providing a different value for `dbCreate` than the value shown in the config snippet above?  If no, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues and link to a sample app we can investigate.

Comment: `dbCreate`  is repeated twice in whole application and it is set to *update* in both places.
Please let me know what other configurations you want to see ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you are seeing.  If you file an issue and share your full config, we will troubleshoot and it and get it straightened out.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do three things,

1. Change dialect to

   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2. and/update mysql driver dependency

   mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17
3. Make sure you are using the correct type in configs (Holders.config.ProfilePictureType) (longtext, maybe)

Comment: Resolved my problem by changing sqlType from `longblob` to `longtext`.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sikander are you saying that `8.0.26-cluster` is not compatible?

Comment: I tested this on 8.0.26-cluster. Working fine with this version as well,
My issue is resolved by using point no 3 from above mentioned points.
Table was not being auto generated because of `longblob` sqlType